# Spring - Adding @Bean to String without name attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

There are [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570821/spring-how-to-inject-a-string-bean-to-the-constructor?rq=1) for adding @Bean on String

> You will have to name the bean, and then use the @Qualifier annotation when autowiring referencing that name.

But in the following code, without name attribute

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:my.properties" })
public class MyEnvironment {

    @Value("${MY_NAME}")            String MY_NAME;
    @Value("${MY_NAME2}")           String MY_NAME2;

    @Bean
    public String getMyName() {
        return MY_NAME;
    }
    @Bean
    public String getMyName2() {
        return MY_NAME2;
    }
}
```

It's called using method as:

```
myEnvironment.getMyName();
```

Isn't `@Bean` redundant/irrelevant in this case? also can this convention cause issues? or is there a hidden benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that Spring's intention is to Inject Dependency, `@Bean` in this scenario is definitely redundant.

Since most of your classes with only make use of, (or you may say - depend on), the configuration object `myEnvironment`.  So it make more sense to inject the `MyEnvironment` class, as a single unit, to those classes that rely on it, not the individual `String` object.

Though, that depends on how you design your classes and their dependencies.  E.g. You can also just injecting those two String values, into the classes that needed it, by using the `@Value` directly on those classes without the need to have the `MyEnvironment` class at all.

Comment: I agree, but theoretically, What will happen if all such properties will have `@Bean` annotation? will it cause issues?

Comment: I believe Spring might throws exception if you have some class that declared `@Autowired` without specifying the `@Qualifier` along with it.

Comment: Yeah, it mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245003/will-spring-throw-an-exception-if-there-is-ambiguity-when-resolving-a-bean

Comment: But we have such class with multiple properties annotated as `@Bean` and Spring doesn't throw exception

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point a bit there.  Declaring multiple properties annotated as `@Bean` is fine, as long as there's no one trying to `@Autowired` them.  It's like spring has its own default mechanism to name those beans, so it won't conflict.  It's only cause a problem when you try to get those beans.  Please checkout: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871789/how-are-beans-named-by-default-when-created-with-annotation